# How to limit regex from grabbing more than one expression

Tags: regex

Here is my regex:`(<ImageContainer)([\s\S]+)([\s\S]+)(<\/ImageContainer>)`

Here is some text I'm grabbing:

```
<ImageContainer>some stuff here...<\ImageContainer>more stuff here..<ImageContainer>and even more stuff</ImageContainer>...
```

My regex is grabbing the whole text and I only want it to grab from `<ImageContainer>` to `</ImageContainer>`. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to get those *some stuff here...s* ?

Comment: its any text. I took it out because it was client specific information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy, [use a lazy quantifier:](https://regex101.com/r/rZ1eM8/1)

```
<ImageContainer>(.*?)<\/ImageContainer>
```

the sequence `.*?` will eat only one character at a time, then try to let the rest of the pattern match. Contrast this with regular greedy `.*`, which will instantly race to the end of the string, and then backtrack to try and let the rest of the pattern match.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!